# Django: Template Doesn't Display Views Field

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm having a problem with a template not displaying model fields sent from a view.

- The url.py correctly directs to the right html template.
- The view debug correctly prints the field contents (title and body) to the terminal, but the template is blank.
- The base.html works, displaying the bootstrap header and container.
  The page source is blank.
- If I replace the for...loop with `<h1>Hi</h1>` the text prints.

Here are the files:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url

    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^news/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    ]
```

---

```
def detail(request, pk):
story = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
print(story)
print(story.body)
print(request)
context = {'story': story}
return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', context)
```

---

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div>
     {% for story in stories %}
        <h1>{{ story.title }}</h1>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got anything called `stories` in the template, but you try and iterate over it. You only have one thing, called `story`; you should just display that directly.

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes. Sometimes you work with code for so long, you lose focus on the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You should write in second paramiter of **render**

Write previos folder.can i khow what is you folder to help exactly??